# Mapping with Searches in Vim

Tags: vim

When, in normal mode, I type the following, the left hand side of an assignment is selected:

```
^v/=
```

That behavoir is not replicated in a seemingly equivalent mapping:

```
onoremap lhs :<c-u>execute "normal! ^v/="
```

What is the difference at work?

Answer (score 6):

You haven't actually concluded the search (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>); to achieve the same effect in the mapping, append `<CR>` (or just use the `f` command for a single-character search):

```
onoremap lhs :<c-u>execute "normal! ^v/=\<CR>"
```

Comment: +1 right solution. `f=` does search in line. `/=` could cross multi lines.